# diagonalization exp(A) counter exemple

Tags: linear-algebra

We consider a finite vector space E over a field K. We consider u in End(E). We can show that if the characteristic polynomial of A splits then we have the following equivalence : A diagonalizable iff exp(A) diagonalizable.

I am searching a counter exemple in the case of a non splitting characteristic polynomial, ie a matrix such that exp(A) is diagonalizable but A is not.

Thankyou for your answers !

Comment: I guess $A = u$, and I also guess you want to require something special about $K$ or $A$ if you want to speak of $\exp A$. Are you interested in archimedean-like situations ($K = \mathbb{C}$) or in formal-power-series-like situations ($K = L\left[\left[x\right]\right]$, $A = xB$, or something like that -- though this probably won't be fields)?

Comment: @darijgrinberg, I suspect the base field is the reals and $A$ has no real eigenvalues. In which case there is an easy 2 by 2 example for this

Answer (score 4):

trying to guess what you might be asking, take
$$ A =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
0 & \pi \\
- \pi & 0
\end{array}
\right).
 $$
Then
$$ e^A =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
-1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{array}
\right).
 $$
If 
$$ C =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
0 & 1 \\
- 1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
 $$
then $C^2 = -I$ and,  for real $t,$

$$  e^{tC} = I + tC - I t^2/2 - C t^3/6 + I t^4/24 +C t^5/120 - I t^6/720-C t^7/5040...$$
$$ e^{tC} = (I - I t^2/2  + I t^4/24  - I t^6/720...) + (tC  - C t^3/6  +C t^5/120 -C t^7/5040...)  $$
$$ e^{tC} = I(1 -  t^2/2  +  t^4/24  -  t^6/720...) + C(t  -  t^3/6  + t^5/120 - t^7/5040...)  $$
$$ e^{tC} = I \cos t + C \sin t $$

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

The other possible interpretation has to do with Jordan blocks. My best guess is that exponentiating does not change the arrangment of Jordan blocks, just the diagonal elements. For example, if
$$ F =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
\lambda & 1 \\
0 & \lambda
\end{array}
\right)
 $$
then
$$ e^F =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
e^\lambda & e^\lambda \\
 0 & e^\lambda
\end{array}
\right)
 $$

But then
$$ 
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
e^{-\lambda} & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
e^\lambda & e^\lambda \\
0 & e^\lambda
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
e^\lambda & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
e^\lambda & 1 \\
0 & e^\lambda
\end{array}
\right)
 $$

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Also did 3 by 3
$$ G =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
\lambda & 1 & 0 \\
0 & \lambda & 1 \\
0 & 0 & \lambda
\end{array}
\right)
 $$
then
$$ e^G =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
e^\lambda & e^\lambda & \frac{1}{2} e^\lambda \\
 0 & e^\lambda & e^\lambda \\
0 & 0 & e^\lambda
\end{array}
\right)
 $$

But then
$$ 
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
e^{-2 \lambda} &  -\frac{1}{2} e^{-\lambda} & 0 \\
0 &   e^{- \lambda} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
e^\lambda & e^\lambda & \frac{1}{2} e^\lambda \\
 0 & e^\lambda & e^\lambda \\
0 & 0 & e^\lambda
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
e^{2 \lambda} &  \frac{1}{2} e^\lambda & 0 \\
0 &   e^\lambda & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
e^\lambda & 1 & 0\\
0 & e^\lambda & 1 \\
0 & 0 & e^\lambda
\end{array}
\right)
 $$

Comment: You are right (+1) ! And I was wrong because I used Wolfram Alpha that gives a wrong result (why?). Thank you.. I've deleted my answer.

Comment: @EmilioNovati, I once made a correction in a Mathematica routine that had been done in a sloppy way and sometimes made errors; twenty years ago, you could read their code for supplementary routines if you had a copy. Later, I had a job interview with them, met S. Wolfram, he really did not care at all. Any particular routine is likely to get corrected over time, but they add new stuff (and new graphics) faster than they can correct it.

Comment: @Will Jagy : Thankyou very much !

Comment: @Anaïs, I just added in a comment about Jordan form, about five minutes after your comment